# How to append to textarea?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How to append to textarea with PHP and then refresh the textarea?

THANK YOU

edit:
It should be server triggered from PHP code

Comment: Could you be more precise? Should this be user triggered oder Server triggered? Could you add some code? Currently your question is a bit too unspecific.

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure what you're after. Do you want to populate a text area when the php script is run then present it to the user, or do you want to do something more "ajaxy" and append to the textarea dynamically?

Comment: There is no way you can change the contents on the client from the server only with using php. Basically this is not possible at all using http, as this protocol is not really intented for this type of communication. But you should have a look at some ajax functionality which can do something like it.

Comment: More ajaxy. PHP does some things and should append to textarea which serves as a log. Textarea is in a separate html-file.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, but we'll need more. Start with the page the user's looking at and tell us what you want to happen?

Comment: How can I call a javascript function from PHP that refreshes the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to have a javascript function that polls the php script using ajax - say every 10 seconds. You could add a timestamp as a parameter to the php function so it only returns the latest log entries.

When the ajax call returns you can append the resulting text to your textarea using javascript.

I could fish out some sample code if you like?

So, here's an HTML file - it has a function to make an AJAX call to a script - log.php that returns some stuff (in this example it's a very simple line of text) and then append this to the text area.

When the script loads we set up a timer to fire every 1000 milliseconds (obviously change this according you your needs).

We've also got a "cancel updates" function and a "start updates".

So - put the html file and the php file (which you need to call log.php - or call it what you like and change the code) into the same directory on your web server and see what happens!.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var http = createRequestObject();
            var updateInt=self.setInterval("updateLog()",1000);


            function startAutoUpdate(){

                if(updateInt==""){
                    updateInt=window.setInterval("updateLog()",1000)
                }else{
                    stop_Int()
                }
            }
            function stopAutoUpdate(){

                if(updateInt!=""){
                    window.clearInterval(updateInt)
                    updateInt=""

                }
            }
            function createRequestObject() {
                var objAjax;
                var browser = navigator.appName;
                if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
                    objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }else{
                    objAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                return objAjax;
            }

            function updateLog(){
                http.open('get','log.php');
                http.onreadystatechange = updateNewContent;
                http.send(null);
                return false;
            }

            function updateNewContent(){
                if(http.readyState == 4){

                    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML + http.responseText;

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Log</h2>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="10" name="log" id="log"></textarea>

        <span onclick="updateLog()">Update</span><br>
        <span onclick="stopAutoUpdate()">Cancel Auto Update</span><br>
        <span onclick="startAutoUpdate()">Start Auto Update</span><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the php script (very simple)...

```
    <?PHP
/* Log responder script
 *
 * When invoked this script returns log entries
 * as this is a sample it just returns a couple of random items
 *
 */

echo "Log Entry ".date("d/m/y h:i:s")."\n";


?>
```